# Is it possible to get the geolocation of Google Plus Feeds which user is following

Tags: ios, api, google-plus

Currently I am working on iOS/android app in which I need to fetch the Geolocations of the feeds/posts on the Google plus for ex.News Company XYZ having page on G+ and they are posting the News feeds on it so I want the feeds with there location programatically for iOS

Does google provide such api to share the geolocation of every Feeds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Location data isn't returned with posts in the current API. Might be worth starring the feature request, or creating a new one with your specific needs: https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=15